# RAW images from new Canon camera not opening in DPP or PS Elements

Tags: canon, raw

When I load my images into my Canon Digital Pro from The Image storage for editing the RAW file will not open. I can see the RAW  on the storage download file but it will only open the JPeg version when I go to open in the edit suite. I have updated the latest Canon Digital Pro software. but this hasn't helped. My Photoshop Elements 15 will not load the RAW files into the Organiser at all only the JPeg saying the RAW file is broken

This is from my new camera a Canon 6D MKll. I have not had this problem with my old camera a Canon 60D.What can I do please?

Comment: Have you tried another SD card? Reformatted your existing one? If the file is broken, you will probably have to live with just the jpg, but you need to test if it's the same for all files on all cards.

Comment: Have you tried taking some test shots saving only raw files to see what happens when you transfer and try to load them? What *exact* version of DPP 4 are you using and on what *exact* operating system? What *exact* firmware version is your 6D Mark II running?

Comment: Hi Guys,I bought a new card and formatted that in the 6D but made no difference .I did also try just shooting RAW and that didn't help either.<y laptop is on Windows 8.Please advise on how I can knowwhat firmware version the 6D is running on>,please excusemy igmorance here

Answer (score 1):

i would say the same as tetsujin.

Otherwise do you have:
1. another computer you can try (or a friend)
2. another card.

If your 2 programs dont work with it and another computer it has to be the card.  they do go faulty and can fail if you battery died during shooting?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Photo.SE. Would you mind updating your answer to be explicit in your recommendation in the first paragraph / sentence? There is no guarantee that comments to questions and answers here will stick around, so it's better to make your answer self-contained. Thanks!